# RxSwift Remove an element BehaviorSubject

Tags: swift, rx-swift, behaviorsubject

I have an BehaviorSubject array. i want to remove a photo from this array by id.

i tried;

```
photosViewModel.favoritePhotos
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .map { photoList in
                photoList.filter { $0.id! != self.currentPhoto.id! } //remove currentPhoto
        }.bind(to: photosViewModel.favoritePhotos)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't "remove an element" from a BehaviorSubject. The closest you can come is to insert a new array into the subject (which will cause it to emit that new array.) Something like this:

```
favoritePhotos.onNext(try favoritePhotos.value().filter { $0.id != currentPhoto.id })
```